# Get storage item in ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to know **how can I get specific item from storage** in ionic by angular .

**Logic**

This is what I have in my local storage

```
item {
  {id: 1, title: xxxx, url: xxxx},
  {id: 2, title: xxxx, url: xxxx},
  {id: 3, title: xxxx, url: xxxx},
};
```

And I need to get specific item like:

```
data {
  id: 1, title: xxxx, url: xxxx
}
```

**Code**

`module`

```
getDetails(url) {
    return this.storage.getItem('item').then((data: any) => {
      this.post.push(data);
    });
}
```

`view`

```
[routerLink]="['/', 'posts', post.url]"
```

## Update

my data in console are like:

[image]

Comment: Is `item` the key/value that you stored in your localStorage?

Comment: @wentjun yes my data are stored under `item` array

Comment: Can you please display that data in console?

Comment: @Juniorcoder sure I make new debug app and will post the results here.

Comment: No need to take build for checking this. Simply type the command ionic serve and check it in the chrome console. Thank you

Comment: @Juniorcoder browser doesn't support storage will get error of cordova doesn't exist , i will inform you once i share the data, thanks

Comment: No way dear. Am using browser to check storage data. May i know which browser you use? Try to Use Google chrome

Comment: @mafortis if you are using `loacalStorage` then you will have to convert data to string to save  ie `localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(data));` and parse the it when retrieving data `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'item'));`

Comment: @mafortis where the you will get the array of object  after parsing the string and then  you can take a particular item from any index you like

Comment: @mafortis do you want to get the data based on the url you passed ? if then `let item = data.filter(value => value.url === url);` and then `if(item && item.length > 0){  this.post = item[0] ; }`